# Extract XmlRoot Info from Class

Tags: c#, xml, class, xmlserializer

How to extract xmlSerializer.mapping (locked attribute) in order to retrieve xmlroot elementname value, namespace value and each xmlattribute attributename?

```
ModelInfo mi = new ModelInfo {ModelName = "Andrea", ModelAge = 23};    
var xs = new XmlSerializer(mi.GetType()); 

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Model", Namespace = "http://ws/")]
public class ModelInfo
{
    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string ModelName{ get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("age")]
    public string ModelAge{ get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it is impossible to retrieve from the XmlSerializer instance.

But you can obtain it like this:

```
ModelInfo mi = new ModelInfo { ModelName = "Andrea", ModelAge = 23 };

var xmlRoot = mi.GetType().GetCustomAttribute<XmlRootAttribute>();

if (xmlRoot != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(xmlRoot.ElementName);
    Console.WriteLine(xmlRoot.Namespace);
}
```